# How to change Python extension locale in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, locale

I can't figure out how to install the Python extension in VSCode in another language, specifically - I want it to be in English, but instead it is being installed in the language of my operating system, which is Russian.

How can I install the Python extension in another language, or change the language to English?

The VSCode installation is in English. My OS is Windows 7.

I've tried googling it, no luck.

~~~
My "locale.json" config:

```
"locale":"en" // Changes will not take effect until VS Code has been
```

Comment: Does this work? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Comment: For the VSCode itself - yes, however, nothing is said there about locales of extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

Apparently the solution was to delete the "en" from "locale.json", type it back in.. restart VSCode.. And now the Python extension is in English. 
"Truly" great design, Microsoft.

In detail the whole procedure is:

1 - Open VSCode

2 - press `Ctrl+Shift+P`

3 - type `Configure Display Language` -> hit Enter

4 - Delete the current locale("en" in my case), type the desired locale in

5 - Save the file

6 - Exit and re-open VSCode

7 - Enjoy the fixed language of the extension.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I wouldn't have thought of this solution. Had the same problem, worked.

Comment: I'm glad it's useful for other people ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Following your instructions, below value worked for me in my "locale.json" config :

```
"locale":"en-US" // Changes will not take effect until VS Code has been restarted.
```